# Disabling loading specific JavaScript files with Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am looking for a way to prevent loading a specific JavaScript file on a website for any website of choice, with Firefox.

For example:
Say I don't want to load jQuery (when loading the page, not afterwards 'disabling' it). I then want to be able to set that

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js
```

should not be loaded. The browser should complete ignore this to debug other JavaScript on the website. I don't have access to the domain directly, so that is why I am trying to do this via the browser.

***So for clarity:*** :) I don't want to disable scripts from a certain domain, but want to be able to disable certain scripts. It can be that 10 scripts are on 1 domain, so killing all 10 of them is not what I want; in that case I want to prevent loading only one.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Related: [Is there a built-in feauture of Firefox allowing to filter webpage's resources being downloaded?](http://superuser.com/questions/361672/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Several options:

1. Use the Addon "Adblock Plus". It will probably still accesses the js but does not execute it.
2. Use the Addon "Greasemonkey", which - when cofigured right - does not even touch the js-url. But its generally harder to configure right. ;)
3. Have a look at Firefox's buildin security policies: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security_Policies  Here you can block javascript on an url or even function-level

Comment: Indeed, AdBlock Plus is a very good tool for that kind of stuff :) The script won't even get downloaded. You can also choose to block this script only on pages in particular domain etc.

Comment: The Firefox Security policies for Javascript are discontinued since Firefox 29: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1000843

Answer (score 2):

Go to your hosts file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` (Windows) or `/etc/hosts` (Linux).

Add:
`127.0.0.1  ajax.googleapis.com` (separated by a tab)

And reopen your browser
This way the jQuery file will fail to load.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this is not working if there are more JavaScripts on the same domain and you want to disable one of them. I have updated my question for clarification.

Comment: @NiklasRingdahl It doesn't even answer the question.

Comment: This worked for me! I just wanted to block a whole domain. For those wanting easy host file access on a Mac, I recommend [hosts for Mac](https://github.com/specialunderwear/Hosts.prefpane).